# Как вытащить данные из JSON при работе с react-simple-typeahead?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

использую -- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-typeahead

```
var cars = require('../cars.json');



 <SimpleTypeahead
  options={['Red', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Blue']}
  onOptionSelected={function(option) { console.log("Option selected:", option)}}
  maxOptionsCount={4}
  placeholder="Type color here"
  customClasses={{
    input: 's-typeahead-input',
    list: 's-typeahead-list',
    listItem: 's-typeahead-list-item',
    listItemSelected: 's-typeahead-list-item--selected'
  }}
/>
```

Подскажите,пожалуйста,как сделать так,чтобы данные брались не из этого массива -- 
  options={['Red', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Blue']}` ,а из подключенного JSON файла?